# Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-7, windows-7-x64

Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 install fails with the below error message, this happens with both the online installer and the ISO, the environment is Windows 7 Enterprise x64 SP1

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this problem, do the following **before** running the update.  But **if it's already too late**, then uninstall the update, then repair the VS2012 install from *Add/Remove Programs* and follow the below steps (you may need to reboot your computer a few times).  More info can be found on this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2013/08/02/installation-of-visual-studio-2012-update-3-fails-with-error-the-pipe-is-being-closed.aspx) (yes blog is for Update 3, but also applies to Update 4)

1. Download the ISO then run extract the contents and navigate to
   "...\packages\WinACK\", and run the below *msp* patches
2. Windows App Certification Kit x64-x86_en-us.msp
3. Windows App Certification Kit Native Components-x64_en-us.msp
4. Run the update exe "VS2012.4.exe"

Note that this is what worked for me.  Would love to hear what others have done to get it to work and share the knowledge especially because I had to struggle because the info was out there in bits and pieces and mostly related to older updates.

Comment: Another option, rather than downloading the ISO, is to point to those files during setup when it asks for them and download the files individually from [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=283370&clcid=0×409) and [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=283372&clcid=0×409) - also detailed at this [other blog](http://fitgeekgirl.com/2013/10/08/installation-of-visual-studio-2012-update-3-fails-with-error-unable-to-locate-package-source/).

Answer (score 0):

I've had other errors relating to the Presentation Framework and the solution for me to was log out of my Domain admin account and log into Windows as a local admin account before installing the update. Not sure if this will work for you too or not, but thought I would mention it.

Comment: I am local admin on the (2) machines I've tested with, and have run with and without elevation with the same results.